# Find grandfather div attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="myclass" value="1">
    <div>
      <div class="myclass" value="">
         <a class="popup" id="12" target="_blank" href="xxx">popup</a>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery with a click event on the popup class, and I am trying to get the value of the grandfather div with class "myclass" which is has a value "1" in the example. I've tried this but it returns me 'undefined'

```
$('.popup').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent('.myclass').parent('.myclass').attr('value')
});
```

Comment: You should really use the console/debugger for this type of stuff. You can also test your selectors in the console.

Comment: `.parent()` only travels one level up so the second time it didn't work. It's completely unuseful in your case anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its an unbalanced braces issue.
You need to close the alert `);` or use `closest` instead of `parent`:

```
alert($(this).closest('.myclass').closest('.myclass').attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `parents` instead of `parent`. `parent` only looks at the immediate parent, and since you have a `<div>` between the two .myclass divs, the selector fails.

```
$('.popup').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).parents('.myclass').parents('.myclass').attr('value');
    alert(val);
});​
```

So in your example, the second `parent` fails because the selector doesn't match because `parent` only looks at the immediate parent. From the [`parent` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) :

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

You can simplify the selector to this, as well:

```
var val = $(this).parent().parents('.myclass').attr('value');
```

A working example can be found [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FKX75/).

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$('.popup').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).parents('.myclass').last().attr('value')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case all code on this page didn't work.
but this work!
var result = $(this).closest('.news').attr('index');